# Protect pages from not logged in user in Nextjs

Tags: redux, next.js, react-redux

I am creating a login page and dashboard for the admin panel using NExtjS and react-redux. Below is the code I have tried. If I login using Id and password I can login and get all the values from the state and everything works fine.
The problem is if I tried to access the dashboard URL directly it says
`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`  
 how can I redirect the user to the login page instead of getting up to return statement ???

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Dashboard = () => {

  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => state);
  const router = useRouter();

console.log(auth) 
// I can get all the objects from state and cookies are set as state for browser reload so everything is fine here.

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth.userInfo && auth.userInfo.role == 'user') {
      router.push('/admin');
      console.log('I am here');
    }
  }, []);
  return <h1>{auth.userInfo.name}</h1>;
};


export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Dashboard), { ssr: false });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the correct way of solving this issue. The correct way was:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req: context.req });
  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
};
```